Definition of friend template of class template
I'm trying to create a class and a friend function for creating this class:
template <typename T>
class test {
    T _value;//[58]

public:
    T value() const { return _value; }

    template <typename Q>
    friend test create_test(Q&& q);
};

template <typename T, typename Q>
test<T> create_test(Q&& q) {
    test<T> temp;
    temp._value = (T)q;//[70]
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    auto t = create_test<int>(7.5f);//[77]
    cout << t.value() << endl;

    return 0;
}


||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC MinGW64 UCRT) ===| ||
In instantiation of 'test create_test(Q&&) [with T = int; Q =
float]':| |77|required from here|
|70|error: 'int test::_value' is private within this context| |58|note: declared private here|
||===
Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|


My initial attempt is this:
template <typename T>
class test {
    T _value;

public:
    T value() const { return _value; }
    friend test create_test<>(T);
};

template <typename T>
test<T> create_test(T value) {
    test<T> temp;
    temp._value = value;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    auto t = create_test(100);
    cout << t.value() << endl;

    return 0;
}

and this works all right, but when I add a second template it doesn't work.

You cannot merge template parameter lists. The correct syntax is template <typename T> template <typename Q> test<T> create_test(Q&&)

not so easy unfortunatly the compiler :error: too many template-parameter-lists|

the solution doesn't work with friend function unfortunatly but only for member function

Define friend function outside class definition when the class and function have separate template parameters
